# Writing audio files with multiple channels in R/Python

Tags: python, r, audio

I'd like to know if there's a good way to write audio objects with multiple channels (such as to .wav files) in R or Python. I use librosa, tuneR, and seeWave but can seemingly only write mono (single-channel) .wav files. The writing functions seem to coerce four channels successively, making a mono audio file that is 4x longer in duration than the original. Any tips on how to fix this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example that creates a stereo Wave object in `tuneR` and saves it as a wav file.

```
library(tuneR)
x <- seq(0, 2*pi, length = 44100)    # make a second of x values
left <- round(32000 * sin(40 * x))   # a low frequency that shows up in the plot
right <- round(32000 * sin(80 * x))  # a different but still low frequency
Wobj <- Wave(left = left, right = right, samp.rate=44100, bit=16)  # make the Wave object
plot(Wobj)
str(Wobj)
writeWave(object = Wobj, filename = 'Wobj.wav')
```

This is the output of the `str` command showing that the left and right slots are different.

```
Formal class 'Wave' [package "tuneR"] with 6 slots
  ..@ left     : num [1:44100] 0 182 365 547 729 ...
  ..@ right    : num [1:44100] 0 365 729 1094 1458 ...
  ..@ stereo   : logi TRUE
  ..@ samp.rate: num 44100
  ..@ bit      : num 16
  ..@ pcm      : logi TRUE
```

And here is the plot.

[image]